# extract coordinates of the center of polygons in a geoJson file in python

Tags: python, plotly, polygon, geojson, centroid

I would like to extract the coordinate of the center of each polygon contained in a geojson file.

here is my geojson file: https://france-geojson.gregoiredavid.fr/repo/departements.geojson

What i want is a list of latitude and longitude of the centers of different departments so i can use it to display the code of the department on a choroplethmap in plotly as a scattermapbox.

How can I do that?

Comment: by center, you mean centroid, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file("https://france-geojson.gregoiredavid.fr/repo/departements.geojson")

df.head(2)

df["lon"] = df["geometry"].centroid.x
df["lat"] = df["geometry"].centroid.y
df
```

Comment: Thank you linog for your answer,
when i try your code i get the following message:
UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'centroid' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.

Comment: That's normal. Your shapefile uses WGS84 (`df.crs`). You lose some precision in geometric manipulations with this projection. If you don't want this warning, you might use some official projected shapefiles from French administration that use Lambert 93

Comment: Ok thank you very much i was able to do the job with your code